# SQL statement that displays items where buying a combo meal is cheaper than buying individual items

Tags: sql, oracle

*NOTE! I am asking for study reasons I have no idea how to write this query, and I haven't been able to find anything like it in references.

Hello stack, so I have this query as an example of using temporary tables in a subquery for a join, and I have literally no idea how to do this. I am mostly doing this for study reasons. Here are the two tables used in the example. Again the query is: Display items where buying the combo is cheaper than buying individual items.

```
create table items(
I# varchar2 (20),
IName varchar2(20),
UnitPrice Number)
;

insert into items
values ('101','Cheese Burger',3.99);
insert into items
values ('102','Double Cheeseburger',4.99);
insert into items
values ('103','French Fries',1.19);
insert into items
values ('104','Medium Drink',1.39);
insert into items
values ('105','Large Drink',1.89);
insert into items
values('106','Combo 1',6.99);
insert into items 
values('107','Combo 2',8.99);

create table itemdetails(
I# varchar2(20),
IncludeI# varchar2(20)
);

insert into itemdetails
values ('106','101');
insert into itemdetails
values ('106','103');
insert into itemdetails
values ('106','104');
insert into itemdetails
values ('107','102');
insert into itemdetails
values ('107','103');
insert into itemdetails
values ('107','105');
```

Any answer would be greatly appreciated. I'm using standard oracle SQL.

Comment: surely you could make an attempt?

Comment: To get yourself started, do something simple.  Find the combo name and the name of each ingredient for all your combos.  Then replace the ingredient names with the sum of the prices.  From there, the `having` clause should finish the job.

Comment: `select i.iname, includei#, i2.iname
from Items i, itemdetails id, items i2
where i.i#=id.i#
and id.INCLUDEI# = i2.I#
order by i.iname
;`

Comment: This gives me the combo and whats in the combo, but when i try to sum the unitprice i get a not a single-group group function error.@DanBracuk

Comment: That's oraclese for "if you have a sum, you need a group by clause".

Answer (score 1):

You could query the sum of the combos (this is the temporary table) eg.

```
select sum(I1.UnitPrice)
from items as I1, itemdetails as I2
where I1.I# = I2.I#
and I1.i# = [one I'm looking at]
group by I1.I#
```

And then search for the combo prices

```
select I3.IName
from items I3
where UnitPrice < [individual prices of I3.I#]
```

Then combine the two.

```
select I3.IName
from items I3
where UnitPrice < 
(
    select sum(I1.UnitPrice)
    from items as I1, itemdetails as I2
    where I1.I# = I2.I#
    and I1.I# = I3.I#
    group by I1.I#
)
```

Comment: Oh wow i think i was over thinking it. I was using self join  on items to show  what the combos included. Then trying to sum those individually compared to the combo. thanks for the answer!

Comment: Usually the simplest way is the clearest even though it may not always be the most efficient.  Only until you become more experience or absolutely need to, should you refactor the query to use advanced syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could join `itemdetails` on `items` twice, once for the price of the combo and once for the prices of the individual items:

```
SELECT   combo.name, combo.UnitPrice
FROM     itemdetails id
JOIN     items combo ON id.i# = combo.i#
JOIN     items individual ON id.i# = individual.IncludeI#
GROUP BY combo.name, combo.UnitPrice
HAVING   combo.UnitPrice < SUM(individual.UnitPrice)
```